# When does custom attribute constructor executes?

Tags: c#, custom-attribute

**Intention :**

I am writing a business application that uses multiple enums where most of these enums exists in tables in the database too. The problem comes in maintenance when one of the team members or a late developer changes an enum member value at one of the two places leaving the enum unsynced. To solve this problem I am trying to create a custom enum attribute that throws some exception when it finds that an enum values are not in sync.

**Implementation :**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Enum)]
public class EnumSyncAtrribute : Attribute
{

    public EnumSyncAtrribute(Type databaseAccessType, Type enumType))
    {

        // Code that uses that databaseAccessType to access the database to get
        // enum values then compare it to values of enumType , goes here.

    }
}
```

Then target enum is marked as follows

```
[EnumSyncAtrribute(typeof(MyDataBaseAccess), typeof(MyEnum))]
public enum MyEnum
{
    value1 = 0,
    value2 = 1,
    value3 = 2
}
```

**Problem :**

The problem is this attribute constructor never executes! I have tried replacing Enums with Classes and found that it executes fine, but with Enums, no!

The question is, when custom attributes are used for enums, when does their constructors executes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attribute class not calling constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470164/attribute-class-not-calling-constructor)

Comment: I came by this thread before I made my post, but unfortunately it couldn't solve my issue.

Comment: What doesn't work when following the other answer?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand what you mean exactly.

Comment: Why didn't that post solve your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute is constructed only when you retrieve it (using the `GetCustomAttribute` function). Otherwise, its *construction recipe* (constructor overload + positional parameters + properties values) is only stored in the assembly metadata.

In your case, I'd retieve all enum types from the assembly, and check if they have the attribute. Something like that at the startup of your application:

```
var allEnumTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                           .GetTypes()
                           .Where(t => t.IsEnum);

foreach(var enumType in allEnumTypes)
{
    var syncAttr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(enumType, typeof(EnumSyncAtrribute)) as EnumSyncAtrribute;
    if (syncAttr != null)
    {
        // Possibly do something here, but the constructor was already executed at this point.
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the only way that causes the Attribute constructor to fire? how come class attributes automatically fires when class is instantiated?

Comment: Yes, it's the only way. And no, they don't fire too.

Comment: Because they're attributes. They're just data unless someone decides to fire them up.

Comment: @user2080257 Just to add to this: I'd rather move your verification code from the attribute constructor to the startup code. This way, the verification won't be accidentally triggered multiple times if some other code deals with reflection. Attributes should limit themselves to data storage.

Comment: @user2080257 The code I posted in the answer, I guess you want to run it at startup

Comment: Please explain more what do you mean by startup, do you mean as in Application_Start event in ASP.net applications for example?

Comment: @user2080257 Yes, that's a good startup point in ASP.NET. But I mean whatever place you put the code of my answer, really.